# Como mudar a cor de uma linha do console em C?

Tags: c, console

então eu gostaria de saber como faço para mudar a cor dessa linha... É um projeto da faculdade e eu já pesquisei em outros fóruns e tudo mais, porém nunca encontro direito uma resposta que faça funcionar. Estou usando o compilador **DevC++ (5.11)**. Quando digo mudar a cor me refiro a mudar tanto de um único caractere, quanto de uma *string* toda ou um vetor.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main (){


    printf("Ola bom dia!");


    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: da uma olhada aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219393/stdlib-and-colored-output-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode verificar os [códigos de escape do ANSI](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_escape_ANSI), então utilizar estes códigos no   `printf`.

Assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define VERMELHO     "\x1b[31m"
#define VERDE   "\x1b[32m"
#define AZUL    "\x1b[34m"
#define RESET   "\x1b[0m"

int main () 
{
    printf(VERMELHO     "Texto em vermelho"     RESET "\n");
    printf(VERDE   "Texto em verde"   RESET "\n");
    printf(AZUL    "Texto em azul"    RESET "\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Então, eu consegui mudar a cor em um compilador online, porém não no DevC++ e como o projeto é pra ser executado nesse compilador, teria alguma outra maneira de ser feita?

Comment: A questão é que essa forma padronizada de mudança de cores nos terminais  funciona em qualquer sistema operacional, exceto no Windows. A microsoft optou por não evoluir a interface de linha de comando dela desde a época do DOS/Windows 3, ~1990;  - então esses comandos ANSI ainda não são padrão no windows hoje em dia

Comment: A solução é buscar por "ansi color codes windows" e verificar as opções - dentre programas alternativos no terminal ou configurações para habilitar as cores ANSI. Fncionar "dentro da IDE" não deveria ser uma preocupação pra você - mas sim, funcionar no terminal.

Comment: @PauloHenrique Você está a confundir alguns conceitos. "o projeto é pra ser executado nesse compilador" - O compilador é para compilar não executar, e é feito com base em algo que você já tem no seu sistema como o gcc, g++, clang, etc, e não com base no IDE que você usa. O DevC++ é um IDE.

Comment: Sim - esse código vai compilar em qualquer comilador. O que não pode ser confundido é ser a IDE, que tem o editor de código, chama o compilador sozinha, e tem um emulador de terminal embutido com "onde o programa roda" -  o emulador de terminal da IDE é só pra evitar ter que trocar de janela pra ver os prints e outras coisas - não tem nenhuma importância para o que o programa de fato faz.